# Persistent static routing configuration on 18.04 Server (CloudInit)

Tags: networking, server, routing, cloud-init

What is the current best practice or de-facto standard to define custom routing for Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Cloud-Init can only set `to`, `via` and `metric` parameters in the main routing table:
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v2.html

My server has 4 additional routing tables + policies (rules). AFAIK the de-facto standard to define static routes was in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Where is the best place to save (make persistent) routes and policies now?

Comment: I miss `src` parameter in cloud-init's route.